# How to access a variable which is inside of a function without defining the variable as global

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, declaration

How can I access to a variable which is inside of a function without defining the variable as a global variable.

```
function name() {
  var name2 = 20;
};

console.log(name2)
```

Comment: There is no way apart from a) assigning it in the scope where you can read it or b) returning it from the function.

Comment: In short: you can't.

Comment: In long: the variable only exists while the function is executing. If the function has not been called yet, the variable never existed. If the function has finished executing, the variable ceases to exist. So… you can't.

Comment: @deceze thanks for explanation

Comment: You might take a step back and describe/demonstrate *why* you want to do this seemingly random thing.  If there's an actual problem you're trying to solve, this question doesn't seem suited to solving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **you can't access a variable declared inside a function outside this function scope**.

And here you are trying to access `name2` variable outside of `naem()` function's scope, this is impossible because a variable declared with `var` keyword is only visible in the  block where it is declared.

If you check **[the `var` MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)** you can see that:

> The **scope of a variable declared with var** is its current execution context, which **is** either **the enclosing function** or, for variables declared outside any function, global. If you re-declare a JavaScript variable, it will not lose its value.

For further details you can check:

- **[`Functions` MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)**.
- **[`Scope` MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)**.

Comment: What about closures?

Comment: It is another thing, here we are tlking about functions and scopes.

Comment: We or you are? A closure clearly satisfies the question in the title in this case.

Comment: @marekful You can make up all sorts of hypothetical situations here obviously, but the question is pretty clearly narrowly scoped.

Comment: @marekful Me or we, closure is another thing here and the code shared in the question is only inferring fu,nctions, variables and scopes.

Comment: Well, I struggle to understand your argument. I can "access a variable which is inside of a function without defining the variable as global" using a closure. Your answer may be misleading.

Comment: You can return it and take its value but you can't really access it, can you change it's value? it will only possible with a closure I know, but I don't think that's what the OP is asking.

Answer (score -1):

Using `clauser`:

```js
function showName (firstName, lastName) {
var nameIntro = "Your name is ";
    // this inner function has access to the outer function's variables, including the parameter
function makeFullName () {     
return nameIntro + firstName + " " + lastName;         
}

return makeFullName ();
}

console.log(showName ("Michael", "Jackson"));
```

Comment: That's a bit overcomplicated…

Comment: @deceze, Now is it fine?

Comment: @HardikShah It's the same think as simple `return name;` as suggested in other answers, in a more complicated way.

Comment: @chŝdk, True and that's why I will stick to `clauser` with parameters.

Comment: Yes, because your last edit was just complicating things.